# Encoding vectors of size $n$ in matrices which less than $2n$ rows

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices

I have a set of vectors and each has $n$ nonnegative entries.
Moreover, each entry of a vector has a *quality*: (1) or (2). It makes $2^n$ different possible patterns.

For example, let's take two vectors of size $n=5$ (the numbers inside the brackets indicate the *quality* of the corresponding entries):

- $x=[1 (1), 2 (1), 1 (2),3 (1), 2 (2)]$, and
- $y=[2 (2), 1 (1), 3 (2),1 (2), 1 (1)]$.

The dot product of such vectors can be defined as follows: only the pairs of entries with the same *quality* are taken into account. In the example we have: $x^Ty=2.1 + 1.3=5$ since only the second and the third pairs of entries share the same *quality*.

Now my problem is the following. For each vector, I want to create a matrix containing the different informations (the entries **and** the *qualities*). All matrices must have the same **number of rows which is the quantity I want to be as small as possible**. The number of columns is not important and can be different between matrices. The product of two matrices $X(r\times k_X)$ and $Y(r\times k_Y)$ is defined in the following way: $$\langle X,Y \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{k_X} \sum_{j=1}^{k_Y} \left(X(:,i)^TY(:,j)\right)^2.$$

By taking the example described above, I can give an easy solution to my problem. If the *quality* of the entry $x_i$ of a vector is (1), we use $[\sqrt{x_i},0]$ and if it is (2), we use $[0,\sqrt{x_i}]$. The number of rows is then $r=2n$ by defining the following matrices:

$$X=Diag([1,0,\sqrt{2},0,0,1,\sqrt{3},0,0,\sqrt{2}]),$$
$$Y=Diag([0,\sqrt{2},1,0,0,\sqrt{3},0,1,1,0]).$$
It is easy to check that with this trick, only the entries sharing the same *quality* collide and that the product is $\langle X,Y \rangle = 5$, as expected.

> Is there a way to encode the different informations in
>   matrices using less than $2n$ rows such that the product would still  be correct in every case? Or is there a way to show it is not possible to do better than $2n$?
>
> In a more general way, do you know if this kind of problem could be
>   related to a particular field?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The first interesting case is when we have two vectors of size $n=2$, e.g. $x=[x_1,x_2]$ and $y=[y_1,y_2]$.
For each vector, there are $2^2=4$ possible patterns for the *qualities* and the corresponding matrices are denoted $X^{(1),(1)}$,$X^{(1),(2)}$,$X^{(2),(1)}$,$X^{(2),(2)}$, and $Y^{(1),(1)}$,$Y^{(1),(2)}$,$Y^{(2),(1)}$,$Y^{(2),(2)}$ respectively.

As explained above, it is easy to find a solution using matrices with $r=2n=4$ rows by defining diagonal matrices.
However, is it possible to find matrices with only $r=3$ rows? They must verify:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\langle X,Y\rangle&Y^{(1),(1)}&Y^{(1),(2)}&Y^{(2),(1)}&Y^{(2),(2)}\\
\hline
X^{(1),(1)}& x_1y_1+x_2y_2 & x_1y_1 & x_2y_2 & 0 \\
X^{(1),(2)}& x_1y_1 & x_1y_1+x_2y_2 & 0 & x_2y_2 \\
X^{(2),(1)}& x_2y_2 & 0 & x_1y_1+x_2y_2 & x_1y_1 \\
X^{(2),(2)}& 0 &x_2y_2 & x_1y_1 & x_1y_1+x_2y_2 \\
\end{array}$$

An attempt **which is only partially correct** with $r=3$ is:
$$X^{(1),(1)}=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{x_1} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{x_2} \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, X^{(1),(2)}=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{x_1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{x_2}\end{pmatrix},\\ X^{(2),(1)}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ \sqrt{x_1} & \sqrt{x_2-x_1} \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, X^{(2),(2)}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ \sqrt{x_1} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{x_2}\end{pmatrix},$$
with which we obtain:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\langle X,Y\rangle&Y^{(1),(1)}&Y^{(1),(2)}&Y^{(2),(1)}&Y^{(2),(2)}\\
\hline
X^{(1),(1)}& x_1y_1+x_2y_2 & x_1y_1 & x_2y_2 & \color{red}{x_2y_1} \\
X^{(1),(2)}& x_1y_1 & x_1y_1+x_2y_2 & 0 & x_2y_2 \\
X^{(2),(1)}& x_2y_2 & 0 & \color{red}{x_2y_2} & \color{red}{x_2y_1} \\
X^{(2),(2)}& \color{red}{x_1y_2} &x_2y_2 & \color{red}{x_1y_2} & x_1y_1+x_2y_2 \\
\end{array}$$
(the red color indicates an incorrect result).

Comment: This appears (from the response to my comment on Bob Terell's answer) to be a homework problem.  I am downvoting and voting to close pending a more satisfactory response to that comment.

Comment: In view of the OP's evasive responses to further comments on Bob Terrell's answer, I will certainly not be changing my close vote.

Comment: I voted to reopen, since the only objection seems to be a misplaced worry about whether it is homework (rather than, say, about the mathematics itself). If a question is interesting, then answer it; if not, then ignore it. Close questions sparingly, only when it is really off-topic (or offensive, etc.). I don't see any particular problem with interesting homework questions. For a student to engage in mathematics on MO seems like a perfectly valid strategy for learning things.  For professors that forbid their students to talk to others about mathematics, I say that it is bad pedagogy.

Comment: I suggest that further discussion about whether the question should be closed or not takes place on the meta post http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2856/probable-homework

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have less than $2n$.
First of all, notice that after you forget about the unimportant details, you want to calculate $\sum_{i=1}^{2n} a_ib_i$ for some $2n$ pairs of numbers using the matrix product you've described. Then realize that in that matrix product the columns are not needed at all, you can just sum up each column to a single entry, so we want $\sum_{i=1}^{2n} a_ib_i=\sum_{i=1}^{r} v_iw_i$, where the $v_i$'s depend only on the $a_i$'s, and the $b_i$'s depend only on the $w_i$'s. Next, we cheat a little and suppose that each $v_i$ (resp. $w_i$) is a linear combination of the $a_i$'s (resp $b_i$'s) - probably it would lead to some pathological contradiction if this was not the case, but now I don't see a proof. And finally, consider what happens if all but one of the $a_i$'s is zero. This gives $2n$ vectors in $\mathbb R^r$ and if $r<2n$, where is some dependency between them. But that would give a contradiction, if multiplied by the appropriate all but one non-zero $b_i$'s.

Comment: In your argument, you use the fact that the length of the vectors is $2n$. But the length is $n$. In the question, I presented an easy solution using two entries for each of the $n$ entries of a vector. But this trick does not rule out the possibility to have a better solution when using matrices. And I do not understand, why do you say the columns are not important?

Comment: That is my point, qualities don't matter at all. Since the operations are distributive, you can just treat each entry+property as one coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, you can do it with one row. Encode quality 1 using nonpositive numbers and quality 2 with nonnegative numbers; the only special case is that you must introduce a negative zero, $-0$ in addition to the usual one. Then the product is $xy = \sum_{i=1}^n {\rm max}(0,x_iy_i)$.

Comment: You are using the $max$ operator but I can only use matrices and $\langle X,Y\rangle$ (as defined in the question) as operator.

Comment: @user90628 :  Why can't you use the max operator?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Because in the definition of the problem, I can only define matrices and then compute the product $\langle X,Y \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{k_X} \sum_{j=1}^{k_Y} \left(X(:,i)^TY(:,j)\right)^2.$. I cannot change the way this product is computed.

Comment: @user90628 : i don't understand this at all.  What defines the problem?  Why don't you want to change the way the product is computed?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Ok, maybe my question is not very clear, sorry for that. So I have a set of vectors and each of the $n$ nonnegative entries has a quality. My problem is to compute the conditional scalar product (the qualities of the corresponding entries must be the same) of two of these vectors. It must be done either by using the standard dot product of two vectors $a^Tb$, or by using symmetric positive semidefinite matrices with the standard inner product $trace(AB)$.

Comment: For the first possibility, there is a solution with vectors of length $2n$. With the example with $n=5$, x=[ 1 (1), 2 (1), 1 (2), 3 (1), 2 (2) ], and y=[ 2 (2), 1(1), 3 (2), 1 (2), 1 (1) ], I can define respectively the following vectors of size $2n=10$: $a=[1 ,0 ,2 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,3, 0,0 ,2]$ and $b=[0 ,2, 1, 0, 0 ,3 ,0, 1 ,1, 0]$. By this way, when computing $a^Tb$, the result is correct in the sense that only the entries with the same quality sum up.

Comment: Now, if I want to use the second possibility, I must find symmetric positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$ such that computing $trace(AB)$ produces the expected result. There is an easy solution: by defining $A=diag(a)$ and $B=diag(b)$ (with $a$ and $b$ as defined earlier), we obtain symmetric positive semidefinite matrices of size $2n\times 2n$ such that $trace(AB)=a^Tb$.

Comment: However, this last solution is only using the diagonal of the matrices, maybe there exist a solution of smaller size using many more entries in $A$ and $B$. So the question is: is it possible to find symmetric positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$ of size $r\times r$, with $r$ smaller than $2n$, such that $trace(AB)=a^Tb$.
Since $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive semidefinite, they can be written: $A=XX^T$ and $B=YY^T$ with $X$ of size $r\times k_X$ and $Y$ of size $r\times k_Y$.

Comment: In this form, the standard inner product of $A$ and $B$ can be written: $trace(AB)=\sum_i^{k_X}\sum_j^{k_Y}(X(:,i)^TY(:,j))^2$, hence the product I defined in my original question.
I used this form, $X$ and $Y$ instead of $A$ and $B$, in order to facilitate the construction of the matrices: the entries of $X$ and $Y$ are not constrained and can take any value, but if I compute $A=XX^T$ and $B=YY^T$, I obtain symmetric positive semidefinite matrices.

Comment: @user90628 :  I lost you at "It must be done".